# Unmet dependencies? Broken packages held?

Tags: linux, dependencies, package, apt

I am trying to get a vpn up and running and am doing so through the shrew soft client. When I go to run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-core libqt4-dev libqt4-gui qt4-dev-tools
```

I get the following stream of output:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt4-core : Depends: libqt4-dbus (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu5~precise1~test1 is to be installed
               Depends: libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu5~precise1~test1 is to be installed
               Depends: libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu5~precise1~test1 is to be installed
               Depends: libqt4-test (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libqt4-xml (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu5~precise1~test1 is to be installed
               Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu5~precise1~test1 is to be installed
 libqt4-dev : Depends: libqt4-dbus (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu5~precise1~test1 is to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-declarative (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu5~precise1~test1 is to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-designer (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-help (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu5~precise1~test1 is to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-qt3support (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu5~precise1~test1 is to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-scripttools (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-sql (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu5~precise1~test1 is to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-svg (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu5~precise1~test1 is to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-test (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-xml (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu5~precise1~test1 is to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-xmlpatterns (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu5~precise1~test1 is to be installed
              Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu5~precise1~test1 is to be installed
              Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu5~precise1~test1 is to be installed
              Depends: qt4-linguist-tools (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: libqt4-opengl-dev (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: libqtwebkit-dev (>= 2.0~) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-gui : Depends: libqt4-designer (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-opengl (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu5~precise1~test1 is to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-svg (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu5~precise1~test1 is to be installed
              Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu5~precise1~test1 is to be installed
 qt4-dev-tools : Depends: libqt4-dbus (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu5~precise1~test1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libqt4-declarative (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu5~precise1~test1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libqt4-help (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libqt4-xml (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu5~precise1~test1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libqt4-xmlpatterns (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu5~precise1~test1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu5~precise1~test1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.9) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu5~precise1~test1 is to be installed
                 Recommends: qt4-designer but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: qt4-doc but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've searched online to no avail. I've ran apt-get -f install and dpkg --configure -a but still am unable to install. I even greped held packages but there was no output. Any ideas as to why or to point me in the right direction? I am chrooted 12.04 precise on a chromebook if that matters.
Cheers

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libqt4-core libqt4-dev libqt4-gui qt4-dev-tools` : Please run $ `sudo apt-get update` ... before (any) package install. -